# hapijs joi validation , validate greater than from sum of other property

Tags: hapi.js, joi

I want to validate a field 'familymemberCount' it should be greater than equal to other fields.
I tried below code, but this not allow to use ' + ' operator with Ref.
How do we validate with sum of other values ?

```
export const familyMemberRulesSchema = Joi.object({
    relationMembers: Joi.object({
        motherCount: Joi.number().integer().min(0).max(5).optional(),
        fatherCount: Joi.number().integer().min(0).max(5).optional(),
        childrenCount: Joi.number().integer().min(0).max(5).optional()
    }),
    familyMemberCount: Joi.number().integer().min(0).max(15).greater(
        Joi.ref('relationMembers.motherCount') +
        Joi.ref('relationMembers.fatherCount') +
        Joi.ref('relationMembers.childrenCount') 
    )
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `joi.ref` doesn't work this way. You need to write a custom function which takes all values and do the sum that way. Basically use `adjust` function while using a `Joi.ref`. Something like this.

```
const Joi = require("@hapi/joi");

const familyMemberRulesSchema = Joi.object({
    relationMembers: Joi.object({
        motherCount: Joi.number().integer().min(0).max(5).optional(),
        fatherCount: Joi.number().integer().min(0).max(5).optional(),
        childrenCount: Joi.number().integer().min(0).max(5).optional()
    }),
    familyMemberCount: Joi.number().integer().min(0).max(15).greater(
        Joi.ref('relationMembers', {"adjust": relationMembers => {
            return relationMembers.motherCount + relationMembers.fatherCount + relationMembers.childrenCount;
        }})
    )
});

const result = familyMemberRulesSchema.validate({"relationMembers": {"motherCount": 2, "fatherCount": 1, "childrenCount": 2}, "familyMemberCount": 6});

console.log(result);

const error = familyMemberRulesSchema.validate({"relationMembers": {"motherCount": 4, "fatherCount": 1, "childrenCount": 2}, "familyMemberCount": 6});

console.log(error);
```