# Conditional validation with joi: Do one thing if a property value is greater than 4, otherwise do something else

Tags: javascript, joi

In joi, I know I can do:

```
.when('propertyName', {
  is: 4,
  then: Joi.number().required(),
  otherwise: Joi.number()
    .strip()
    .optional()
    .allow(''),
})
```

However, rather than triggering the "then" when `propertyName` is equal to 4, I want to trigger it when `propertyName` is greater than 4. How can I do this? Note that `propertyName` can be any floating point number, not just integers.

Comment: did you try `max()`. just a hint. like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60316685/hapijs-joi-validation-validate-greater-than-from-sum-of-other-property) one

Comment: Different situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `is: 4`, do `is: Joi.number().greater(4)`