# How to validate sum of refs in Joi

Tags: javascript, typescript, joi

How can I validate the total of two refs as below? I would prefer have `custom` be on the `total`, yet unsure of how to get the value of the `refs` in the custom when using `Joi.ref`.

I can do the following and hang a `custom` off the entire validation schema, but would prefer to attach it to `total`.

I don't want to use [expression()](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.2#expressiontemplate-options---aliases-x)

I prefer not to change the schema structure as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60321522/62282).

```js
  const widgetValidator = Joi.object({
    a: Joi.number().integer().min(0).required(),
    b: Joi.number().integer().min(1).required(),
    total: Joi.number().integer().min(1).required(),
  }).custom((value: {a: number; b: number; total: number;}, helpers) => {
      if (value.total !== value.a + value.b) {
        throw new Error('invalid balance calculation');
      }

      return value;
    },
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install `custom` on an attribute, it will be a little hard to get whole object values. You have to get it from [helpers's states](https://joi.dev/api/#anycustommethod-description):

```js
Joi.object({
    a: Joi.number().integer().min(0).required(),
    b: Joi.number().integer().min(1).required(),
    total: Joi.number().integer().min(1).required().custom((value, helpers) => {
      const { a, b } = helpers.state.ancestors[0];
      if (value !== a + b) {
        throw new Error('invalid balance calculation');
      }

      return value;
    },
  )
})
```

Comment: Thanks, some casting is needed for TS but works like charm.